# Bouyancy and Normal force at a fully submerged object

Tags: forces, pressure, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics, buoyancy

I learned as a child that

in a fully submerged object (which is touching the bottom of the fluid tank), the normal force "N" by the tank's bottom to the object is `N=weight-bouyancy`.

However I recently understood that bouyancy is just a simple way to use pressure difference by gravity.
If so, considering a cylinder in a fluid with a top surface A, There are mainly three vertical forces. 1. Force P*A due to pressure on top surface 2. W due to gravity 3. Normal force N by tank bottom. `Then, isn't the normal force N=W-PA?`.

I think The main difference is whether there is fluid to give pressure at the bottom surface.

Do I understand bouyancy or normal force wrong? Isn't pressure just another form of normal force?
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/516148/231654 Possible Duplicacy. The first post should answer your question. BTW, the latter expression should be $N= W + PA$ and not $N = W - PA$

Comment: wow you're right. Thanks!!!

Comment: btw should I delete this question??

Comment: @Med Just leave the question and we will mark it as a duplcate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does buoyant force vanish if there is no liquid below an object?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373239/)